# how to import a dynamic web project into IBM Rational Application Developer 9.0 was 8.5

Tags: java, rad

I have some application hosted on was 6.1. Now I have to test those application in rad 9 was 8.5. But I cannot find dynamic web project import in rad 9.

How to import a dynamic web project into IBM Rational Application Developer 9.0 using WAS 8.5 as server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all during the installation of RAD through Installation Manager, you need to make sure that you have installed the WAS 8.5 tooling option.

Assuming that you took care of the above point, you can simply use the "File -> Import --> General --> Existing Projects into workspace" option. You can either point to the exact location of the existing dynamic web project that you wish to work with or if the project is in a zip format, you can point to the location of the zip.

Hope this helps.

Thanks,
Gaurav

Comment: imported as java project then changed it to faceted one